# Is there a name for an undirected graph that comes from removing the arrows from a DAG?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

If I have a directed acyclic graph and I take the underlying undirected graph does this graph have a name or have these types of graphs been studied before?

I am interested in the properties of treewidth of these graphs but when I try and find information out on them I can only find information about the DAG-width of directed graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a structured graph. Any undirected graph can be represented by some starting DAG and making all edges undirected.

Any undirected graph G can be transformed into a DAG (and therefore back again by making the edges undirected) by choosing a total order for its vertices and directing every edge from the earlier endpoint in the order to the later endpoint. A total order can be obtained by assigning to each newly visited vertex along a DFS of G the value of an incrementing counter.

Making all edges undirected basically removes the only two properties (directed and acyclic) separating a DAG from an arbitrary undirected graph.